# Detecting when an image intersects a certain color?

Tags: java, colors, game-engine, intersection

I am 11 years old, and I program with Java, HTML, and CSS. Well what I have is a game, and its a Minecraft 2D Platformer.

Well I have some water to the side, and what I want to do is when the player intersects that water, I want it to slow down. Here is a example if there was a method to do this, in case you still don't understand my goal.

```
if (player.intersectsColor("0026FF"))
    playerSpeed = 2;
else
    playerSpeed = 3;
```

Comment: Noah, I'm sorry other users here are downvoting you instead of offering up advice or asking more clarifying questions. Are you asking whether Minecraft has such a method as intersectsColor, or are you asking if this would be a proper way to do it if the method did exist?

Comment: @BrianReindel the code that i added was the example if such a method existed in the `Image` class. What I am asking is how do I execute code when the `Image` `player` intersects some color, in this case, blue with the color code of 0026FF. What I am wanting is for when the player goes into the water (0026FF), then decrease the playerSpeed integer by one. the reason i say `playerSpeed = 2` instead of `playerSpeed--` is because this is going to be running in a loop, and what it would do is subtract to the one from it every millisecond spent in the water.

Comment: You may find that you'll have a greater response over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or even on one of the communities for Minecraft https://minecraft.net/community. It seems more specific to Minecraft than it does to Java.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you represent the water not by its color but by its location.  That way you can check whether the player is in a "tile" representing water, and adjust the speed accordingly.

This you can do with simple comparison on the x/y coordinates (adjusted for the size of the "tile"/"player")

If you don't have nice meshy tiles, but curves/polygons, you will need to read up on geometry and how to calculate (possibly curved) line intersection.  The exact algorithm will depend on the curve used.

The reason I discourage you from using the color itself for the intersection many twofold:

1. "Intersecting" on a single color limits your ability to dynamically color the terrain/objects later
2. You cannot have two different terrain.object type with the same color
3. Having the color (e.g. brown) of the terrain/object does not tell you which blue terrain/object the player ran into (e.g. is it the first or the second chest?)

If you *really* want to represent the terrain with colors, you can translate the players in-game coordinates to screen coordinates and see what color pixel you have at that coordinate on the screen (before the player was rendered on the scene), but this is messy.

Comment: Ok, well I put the water on the background image, and its curved, thats what im needing help on